# Which stabilizes a carbocation more : Back Bonding or Conjugation?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Suppose we take these two compounds:

[image]

The first carbocation can rearrange to produce the second one by hydride shift. Which is more stable ? Why ?

Comment: The compound to the left seems like a carbonyl in disguise. How did you get there?

Comment: @Variax Hydride shift.

Comment: @Variax http://chem.libretexts.org/Reference/Organic_Chemistry_Glossary/1,2-Hydride_Shift

Comment: What I meant is how did you obtain the first carbocation in the first place?

Comment: By heating a diol with concentrated sulfuric acid and then a hydride shift. I don't think it matters how I got the carbocations. I just want to compare the relative stabilities of the two interconvertible structures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am inclined to consider the second one as a "bona-fide" carbocation, if that makes sense. The first one resembles a protonated aldehyde rather than a carbocation, so relatively speaking, the first one should be more "stable".

Comment: The question deserves a more thorough answer than ‘I think’.